# Mathematica will not run Arnoldi method while using NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, linear-algebra, precision-and-accuracy, arbitrary-precision

This is simplified version of my real code:

```
mat[x_] := {{x^2, 1, 0}, {1, x^2, -1}, {0, -1, x}}
ei[x_] := Eigensystem[
    mat[x],
    1,
    Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}
    ][[1, 1]]
NIntegrate[ei[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

and Mathematica gives me this error:

```
Eigensystem::arm: Method -> Arnoldi can only be used for matrices of machine- or arbitrary-precision real numbers.
```

I tried changing WorkingPrecision of NIntegrate, fixing the precision, and changing the code to:

```
mat[x_] := SetPrecision[{{x^2, 1, 0}, {1, x^2, -1}, {0, -1, x}}, 20]
ei[x_] := Eigensystem[
    SetPrecision[mat[N[x, 20]], 20],
    1,
    Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}
    ][[1, 1]]
NIntegrate[ei[N[x, 20]], {x, 0, 4}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

Still did not help. Why this is happening?

I need to use Arnoldi method to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, since my real matrix is very big and I am interested in couple of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: You need to insert `x_?NumericQ` somewhere in your definitions to thwart the attempt at symbolic preprocessing.

Comment: @J.M., I have changed the declarations of the variables in the functions with `x_?NumericQ`, as well as added the option: `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}`. Did not help, I am still getting the error.

Comment: Are the values you're getting with this actually correct though?

Comment: @Feyre, you mean eigenvalues, or the result of the integration?

Comment: Either? If not, what are you expecting?

Comment: In my real physics problem, I will need arbitrary precision to calculate the eigenvalues, since the matrix is actually big. But I need only a few eigenvalues. I think this method gives the correct results for the toy problem I wrote above.

Comment: @gurluk: part of your problem is that you are thinking in terms of "declarations", a concept from other programming systems. This is foreign to Mathematica. `x_NumericQ` is not a declaration, but a constrained pattern, a very different beast.

Comment: @JohnDoty, yes, I think I am still thinking in terms of other programming languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mat[x_?NumberQ] := {{x^2, 1, 0}, {1, x^2, -1}, {0, -1, x}}
ei[x_] := 
 Eigensystem[mat[x], 1, 
   Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}][[1, 1]]
NIntegrate[ei[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

(* 8. *)

Comment: This does not get rid of the error message, nor change anything.

Comment: It worked for you? :) What? I am copying the same code and it still gives the same error? haha

Comment: This works. For those who say it doesn't (@Feyre) : probably you forgot to clear your old definitions of `mat` that don't contain the restriction! So I'd suggest adding `Clear[mat]` in front of the answer.

Comment: @rewi, now works.

Comment: @Jens, I cannot believe the problem was actually so small and easy. I was expecting something related to arbitrary precision, I think I overthought :) Thank you both.

Comment: @Jens, it also worked in my real problem. Thank you.