# "Arnoldi" method for Eigenvalues inside FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, eigenvalues

I'm trying to implement a function which, given a matrix with one free parameter, would return the value of the parameter at which the lowest eigenvalue of the matrix is equal to a certain number.

Importantly, I'm planning to run this algorithm for extremely large sparse matrices, so I would like to use Arnoldi method.

Here's my attempt:

```
FitMat[matrix_, lowest_, param_, starting_, howmany_] := 
  Module[{mat, fu},
   mat[x_] := matrix /. {param -> x};
   fu[x_] := Min[Eigenvalues[mat[x], howmany
      , Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}
      ]];
   Return[
    x /. FindRoot[fu[x] == lowest, {x, starting}
      ]
    ];
   ];

FitMat[( {
   {1, 2, 1},
   {3, 4, 1},
   {x, 4, 9}
  } ), -3, x, 50, 1]
```

This, however, results in the following error:

```
Eigenvalues::arm: Method -> Arnoldi can only be used for matrices of machine- or arbitrary-precision real numbers.
```

Please note that replacing `mat[x_]` and/or `fu[x_]` with `mat[x_?NumericQ]` and/or `fu[x_?NumericQ]` totally ruins the code, even if the `Method` specification is not used.

Could anyone please fix my solution or come up with a better one?

(Of course, the problem I'm trying to solve is highly non-linear; however, I typically do have a pretty good estimate for the value of `starting`. So, for small matrices the same code without specifying the `Method` works well.)

Comment: Does defining the function give this error? Or calling it? If so, what are the arguments?

Comment: Calling. Provided an example.

Comment: What do you mean by ``fu[x_?NumericQ]`` totally ruins the code? Without it I'm getting messages about a singular Jacobian whenever I try to insert the initial condition inside the function to avoid that issue.

Comment: However, if you just comment the line with `Method`, the code works as it should.

Comment: I was just drawing the parallel with [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118212/mathematica-will-not-run-arnoldi-method-while-using-nintegrate) question - in my case, adding `_NumericQ` to definitions does not seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are a few things going on.

First, as the error message says, the `Arnoldi` method requires machine- or arbitrary-precision real numbers.  Your matrix is made of integers, hence the message.

Second, you do need `fu[x_?NumericQ]` to avoid `FindRoot` from prematurely evaluating `fu` without a number.

Finally, for your example, there appears to be no such root.  If you insert

```
Print[Plot[fu[x], {x, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> All]];
```

into `FitMat`, you'll see

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly, this never equals -3, so `FindRoot` fails.

If you try

```
FitMat[({{1., 2., 1.}, {3., 4., 1.}, {x, 4., 9.}}), 15, x, 50, 1]
```

instead, you get the answer `63.0769` with no errors or messages.

**EDIT:**

To find where the smallest (most negative) eigenvalue equals `-3` you can use the `-1` option for the `Arnoldi` method together with a `Shift`.  No `Min` needed!

```
FitMat[matrix_, lowest_, param_, starting_] := 
  Module[{mat, fu}, mat[x_] := matrix /. {param -> x};
   fu[x_?NumericQ] := 
    Eigenvalues[mat[x], -1, 
     Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart", 
       "Shift" -> -1000}];
   Print[Plot[{fu[x], lowest}, {x, -100, 100}, PlotRange -> All]];
   Return[x /. FindRoot[fu[x] == lowest, {x, starting}]];];

FitMat[({{1., 2., 1.}, {3., 4., 1.}, {x, 4., 9.}}), -3, x, 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(* 52. *)
```

Comment: If you run `Eigenvalues[( {
   {1, 2, 1},
   {3, 4, 1},
   {52., 4, 9}
  } )]`, you will see that the lowest eigenvalue is `-3`.

Comment: Yes, but your `Min` is outside the `Eigenvalues[{{1, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {52., 4, 9}}, 1, 
 Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]`, which returns only one eigenvalue (the largest), so you might need to rethink you approach.

Comment: Try `Eigenvalues[{{1, 2, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {52., 4, 9}}, -1, 
 Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart", "Shift" -> -1000}]` instead -- see [this answer by @CarlWoll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/182407/6358).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and comments! I was confused because of misunderstanding what `"Criteria" -> "RealPart"` does.